# Landscape dimensiones being ignored

Tags: android

I have an app where I enforce portrait on the Manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/launcher_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

</activity>
```

I do go landscape manually on certain conditions using:

```
 private fun triggerPortrait() {
        this@DashboardListActivity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
    }

    private fun triggerLandscape() {
        this@DashboardListActivity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
    }
```

Now I want certain elements to change their size when the orientation is landscape, so i have these two dimens.xml

dimens-land.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="scoreboard_height">24dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

dimens-port.xml

```
<resources>

    <dimen name="scoreboard_height">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

However the switch between one and the other is not working at all, only the landscape one is being used. I guess this has to do with me enforcing portrait, but is there a way to fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try just renaming dimens-port.xml to dimens.xml ?

Comment: I did try that yes, but then land is ignored

Comment: That's strange, it should cascade. Did you also try naming both as just dimens but putting the landscape copy inside a -land package?

Comment: yeah sorry thats how i had it

Comment: Then it all sounds correct. Perhaps you can add a screenshot of the resources part of your project panel in the IDE

Comment: I just did now, currently i have dimens.xml on values and values-land folders

Comment: Ok, last attempt - post where you are using the value (xml or code). Because everything still looks correct so far

Comment: Maybe this adds to the diagnostic: This is a library project

Answer (score 1):

You could remove `android:configChanges="orientation"` from your manifest entry for `MyActivity`. But since that is not desirable and declaring a configuration with this attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted and instead, the activity remains running and its [onConfigurationChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)) method is called and you are expected to note the configuration change and apply the logic that you would like instead in an override of `onConfigurationChanged()`.

So here is how to accomplish doing it manually,

Copy those dimen values to one values/dimens.xml file that is globally available

values/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="scoreboard_height_land">24dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="scoreboard_height_port">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Update the orientation dimens to point to those values by its key (just in case you are re-using them else where in your app w/o all this logic and those areas do not break)

values-land/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="scoreboard_height">@dimen/scoreboard_height_land</dimen>
</resources>
```

values-port/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="scoreboard_height">@dimen/scoreboard_height_port</dimen>
</resources>
```

Override onConfigurationChanged to set the new height of the scoreboard

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setHeightOfScoreboardViewBasedOnOrientation(newConfig.orientation);
}

public void setHeightOfScoreboardViewBasedOnOrientation(int orientation) {

    // change the id to match what you have in your xml (since i dont know it at the time of writing this)
    View myScoreboardView = findViewById(R.id.myScoreboardView);

    // get the layout params and set a new height, then set it back n the view
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams myScoreboardViewLayoutParams = myScoreboardView.getLayoutParams();
    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        myScoreboardViewLayoutParams.height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.scoreboard_height_land);
    } else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        myScoreboardViewLayoutParams.height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.scoreboard_height_port);
    }
    myScoreboardView.setLayoutParams(myScoreboardViewLayoutParams);

}
```

Note: 
You could likely call the `setHeightOfScoreboardViewBasedOnOrientation` method from `triggerPortrait` and `triggerLandscape` methods with `Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` or `Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE`. But handling configChanges are more fun to learn, especially when your the activity is in the back stack and the orientation changes!!!

Comment: I put this line because I needed it, so I need to work my way around this problem...

Comment: Then you likely want to implement detecting that change in you activity's `onConfigurationChanged()` and applying the new height there.

Comment: I did that, however i dont know how to tell the OS to use the dimens from landscape!

Comment: so theres absolutely no way to apply different styling other than doing it manually?

Comment: There is, but you'd have to forgo that manifest entry for configChanges="orientation".